# Drop temp table if it exists - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I always used to use the code below to check for a temp table before deleting it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#InvoiceAdjustments') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #InvoiceAdjustments;
```

but something has changed somewhere and now I get an error as below:

> Incorrect syntax near ' '.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 with SSMS v18.4

I've also had the same error with this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] LIKE '#InvoiceAdjustments%') 
        DROP TABLE #InvoiceAdjustments;
```

Can anyone suggest why this no longer works?

Comment: Post a [mre], that code works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9c765794ab02c094e1c27c033e1f329). Also, why are you still using 2008R2? It's been completely unsupported for 18~ months.

Comment: Is there a statement just before that one that is missing something?

Comment: If there are no surrounding statements; you might have an invisible character stuck in there somewhere.   It's lost when you post it here so we can't recreate the problem. Start up a new query tab and cut-n-paste from standard windows notepad to retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was some kind of invisible character as suggested by vhoang.

I just typed it out again exactly as it was before and it worked fine.  Many thanks for the suggestion!